# Does a Filipino passport holder resident in New Zealand need a visa to enter South Korea?

Tags: visas, south-korea, filipino-citizens, new-zealand

I live in New Zealand but I have a Filipino passport with a student visa in it. Do I need to get a visa if I want to go to South Korea from New Zealand?

Answer (score 3):

A Filipino passport holder normally requires a visa to visit South Korea, however according to Timatic, Filipino passports with a visa for New Zealand can enter visa free.

> Korea (Rep. of), South - Destination Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> **The following are exempt from holding a visa**:
>   **Nationals of Philippines with a visa issued by** Austria, Belgium, Canada, Cyprus, Czechia,
>   Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland,
>   Ireland (Rep.), Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg,
>   Malta, Netherlands, **New Zealand**, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania,
>   Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, USA or United Kingdom
>   and a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within
>   30 days. They must be returning from the country that issued the visa.
>
> Nationals of Philippines with a visa issued by Austria, Belgium,
>   Canada, Cyprus, Czechia, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany,
>   Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Ireland (Rep.), Italy, Latvia,
>   Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, New Zealand,
>   Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden,
>   Switzerland, USA or United Kingdom and a confirmed onward ticket for a
>   flight to the country that issued the visa within 30 days. The
>   following itineraries are possible:
>   - arrive from a third country and departing to the country that issued the visa (e.g. DEL-ICN-YVR); or
>   - arrive from a third country and depart to another country for a maximum stay of 3 days, before departing to the country that issued
>   the visa (e.g. DEL-ICN-SGN-YVR); or
>   - arrive after transiting through a third country for a maximum of 3 days (e.g. DEL-SGN-ICN-YVR).
>
> Nationals of Philippines traveling as tourist, if arriving at and
>   departing from Jeju (CJU) for a maximum stay of 30 days. They must
>   hold confirmed tickets and other documents for their next destination.
>
> Passengers with an APEC Business Travel Card valid for travel to "KOR"
>   for a maximum stay of 90 days. The card is valid for the countries
>   listed on the back of the card.

(emphasis added)

Note it does say that you require an onward ticket within 30 days,